# Only hide Tab Bar on one view inside navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` that has `hidesBottomBarOnPush` set to true in the storyboard. The view is pushed on top of a `UINavigationController` stack. This `UINavigationController` is inside a `UITabBarController`. This successfully hides the `UITabBar` on push. However, when I push another view on top of that, the `UITabBar` is still hidden (even though `hidesBottomBarOnPush` is set to false in the storyboard). How can I make it only hide the `UITabBar` for that one view?
Thanks!

Comment: You should show it in the code before pushing new controller.

Comment: @biloshkurskyi.ss You were correct, I needed to add the code into my viewWillAppear before pushing the views, instead of using storyboard.

Comment: post your code and check as correct answer. Also you are welcome.

Comment: Actually I don't think this is right, because I've noticed although the tab bar shows, the insets dont adjust

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `false` to `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`

```
override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    get {
        return navigationController?.topViewController == self
    }
    set {
        super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
    }
}
```